# Nrwl Nx: Merging lib into a publishable lib

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a Nx workspace and want to build two npm packages: one for React and one for Angular. Both using some shared code.

The structure is like this:

- lib

  - core
  - react-lib
  - angular-lib

If I make the core library publishable and want to publish angular-lib to npm I need to publish the core package as well, which I don't want.

If the core is not publishable I get the File xxx.ts is not under 'rootDir'

Does anyone know if its possible to create an angular-lib package with the used code of the data lib included?

Here the [code](https://github.com/Marcelh1983/angular-document-viewer/tree/multi-target)

Comment: It probably does what you’re expecting? You’re not actually importing the data module so my guess is the contents of it are actually included in the angular-lib build?

Comment: It creates two libs one depending on the other, so if I would publish angular-lib I need to publish @project/data as well. I think it's designed like this, so probably need another way to share the code

Comment: It would create the data lib as well... however, looking at the way you're using it now, I would expect the functionality from data to be included in the build of angular-lib - so you wouldn't 'need' the data lib anymore after build (unless it is also used or imported somewhere in your actual app)

Answer (score 0):

maybe [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is what you really need.

So if you do not want to pulish 'core', but want that module be reusable between react-lib and angular-lib. You just hook up repo of 'core' as a submodule to repos of 'react-lib' and 'angular-lib' and have file structure like as follows

core - has its own git repo

angular-lib - has its own git repo and 'core as submodule'.

./src

./core - git submodule

react-lib - has its own git repo and 'core as submodule'

./src

./core - git submodule

you can update entire angular-lib including subdirectory 'core' with single command '`git pull --recursive`'

From angular's and react's point of view that 'core' is just a subdirectory, you can import source files from there etc. '`ng build`' will include all neccessary into resulting bundle. So code from 'core' is reusable and updatable from git and no need to publish npm package for that.

Or - approach #2 - just use symlinks. Make symlink to directory of 'core' in directories of 'angular-lib' and 'react-lib'. And import source code from ./core. 'ng build' will create proper bundle - it will include copy of files, no symlynks.

Comment: I too have same issue, and the first approach won't help me as we need to maintain single repo. The second approach of symlinks works fine, but I am wondering whether we have any other approach by using configurations to make the library(core lib) code get build inside angular build.